# ArgumentException: The parameters dictionary contains an invalid entry for parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

There are different Action in a controller. Two links, one to each action (as menu)
Clicking on each work without problem, switching between the two actions by clicking on links raises following error (sometimes)

> [ArgumentException: The parameters dictionary contains an invalid entry for parameter 'vm' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult 
>   Overview(Poject.Areas.Area1.Models.ViewModel2VM)' in 'Poject.Areas.Area1.Controllers.ControllerA'. The dictionary contains
>   a value of type 'Poject.Areas.Area1.Models.ViewModel1VM', but the
>   parameter requires a value of type
>   'Poject.Areas.Area1.Models.ViewModel2VM'. Parameter name: parameters]
>          System.Web.Mvc.ActionDescriptor.ExtractParameterFromDictionary(ParameterInfo
>   parameterInfo, IDictionary`2 parameters, MethodInfo methodInfo) +733

Most of the times is works, sometimes the error is displayed. All ViewModelClasses inherit from same ViewModelBase class. Could this be a reason?

Any help welcome

Comment: I get this error after just adding "virtual" to the controller method. The message references the controller class name ending in "Proxy" - so it relates to the [Transaction] NHibernateIntegration attribute I'm using on that method

Answer (score 0):

The error seems fairly clear: You need a type `Poject.Areas.Area1.Models.ViewModel2VM`, but are in some cases passing the type `Poject.Areas.Area1.Models.ViewModel1VM`.

If `ViewModel1VM` amd `ViewModel2VM` are more or less equivalent, then perhaps you can solve this by creating a common class that they inherit from, and use that as the parameter type, so that the method `Overview()` will accept both types.

Comment: Yes, I understand that 'the wrong' ViewModel class is loaded. But how can this happen? I do not give any arguments with the links.